# Adding ShockwaveFlash control throws error

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

Migrating VB6 to vb.net code Adding `ShockwaveFlash` control throws error:

```
Public WithEvents ShockwaveFlash1 As AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash

ShockwaveFlash1 = Controls.Add("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash", "ShockwaveFlash1", Me)
```

Above line throws Error

> Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Control'

But it works fine in VB6.

Comment: `Controls.Add(ShockwaveFlash1)`